# Inheritance in c++ base constructor called

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why is my base class constructor called this this instance?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

A

B

Why is A called before B is? And why is A even called in the first place?

Comment: Because that's how constructors and classes work, in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so does it always call the base constructor and work it's way up each derived step?

Comment: See the linked question for the explanation.